# How can i set my images to resize and move if the window ratio is changed

Tags: html, css

I have three images and i want to add some code that makes it so the images sizes changes if the window's size/ratio is changed. I just want to add that i'm really new to programming and even more html so if you could be understanding and answering in a simple way, thanks!

Comment: You would need to constantly listen to the `window` `resize` event and calculate the ratio and act accordingly, for example, update the `style` attribute of your images. This is the naive option. This depends on exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find out what kind of questions Stack Overflow [is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) intended for. This question is [asking for a solution without attempting to show any work](https://can-i-haz.codes/). Please provide some code to help us work with you to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Glad you've decided to start getting involved in programming and HTML! I hope you're having fun ♥

When we are styling our components on a web page, we should think about it separately to the mark-up (HTML). HTML describes the structure of our page, but *CSS* describes the look and feel of it.

To make your image scale, you should provide a CSS rule to describe it. For example if you wanted to make your image take up 50% of the container it is contained in you would have the rule:

```
.image {
   width: 50%;
}
```

This rule should be defined in a separate file e.g. `style.css`, and should be linked to your HTML page using a reference:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Finally, to apply the style rule to your HTML element, you need to reference the class from your stylesheet, e.g.:

```
<img src="..." class="image"  />
```

You can see an example of CSS being use to scale an image here:  https://jsfiddle.net/yp5fd41h/, by stretching the window left and right, the size of the image will change

Comment: Okay thank you, and yeah I already have set up a stylesheet and I am going to try themethod you described me.